# How can I create a new portal in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a new portal with an id .

This is the index html file in the public folder :

```
 <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="other"></div>
  </body>
```

And here I tell react to render this component inside the div with the id of root :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function New() {
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(<h1>DEMO</h1>, document.getElementById('other'));
}

export default New;
```

But when I npm start I dont see anything inside the div with the id of other .

How can I create a new portal in react js properly ?

Comment: Works fine for me. Any errors in console?

Comment: @Drag13 Nothing at all

Comment: here is an example https://codesandbox.io/s/r8s1i?file=/src/Modal/Modal.js:465-474

Comment: Are you rendering New() in App.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by including the New component inside App.js file :

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import New from './New';

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <New />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

And when I inspect it , the New component is actually inside the div with the id of other .